Ansible data formatting and looping
I'm getting to grips with Ansible, I'm still pretty new to many basic concepts, so please bear with me.
My first target is to configure lists of interfaces on several devices. As input, I've got CSV files, one per device. Each line contains parameters, which will be used by a role task to configure the device via API.
I want to loop through each interface for each device to apply the desired config.
The data structure of the files is:
$ cat files/panos/interfaces/fw1.site1.csv
intf,comment,mode,tag,vlan_name,vr_name,ipv4,ipv6,zone,mtu,netflow,lldp,mgmt,speed,duplex,state
ethernet1/1,Dot1Q trunk to xyz,layer2,,,,,,,,,trusted,,,,
ethernet1/1.2,Some VLAN,layer2,2,vlan_2,,,,zone1,,,,,,,

$ cat files/panos/interfaces/fw2.site.csv
intf,comment,mode,tag,vlan_name,vr_name,ipv4,ipv6,zone,mtu,netflow,lldp,mgmt,speed,duplex,state
ethernet1/3,To fw1.site,layer3,,,,169.254.255.1/31,,zone1,,,trusted,ping,,,
ethernet1/4,To fw1.site,layer3,,,,169.254.255.3/31,,zone1,,,trusted,ping,,,

The playbook I'm testing with:
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    confs: "{{ dict(pan_hosts|zip(c_vals)) }}"
    c_vals: "{{ conf.results|map(attribute='list')|list }}"
    pan_hosts: "{{ conf.results|map(attribute='item')|
                             map('basename')|
                             map('splitext')|
                             map('first')|list }}"

  tasks:
    - read_csv:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      with_fileglob: "files/panos/interfaces/*.csv"
      register: conf
    - debug:
        var: confs
    - name: test1
      debug:
        msg: "{{ pan_hosts }}"
    - name: test2
      debug:
        msg: "{{confs[item]|to_nice_yaml}}"
      loop: "{{ pan_hosts }}"

This gives the following output:
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

{'fw2.site': [{'intf': 'ethernet1/3', 'comment': 'To fw1.site', 'mode': 'layer3', 'tag': '', 'vlan_name': '', 'vr_name': '', 'ipv4': '169.254.255.1/31', 'ipv6': '',
'zone': 'zone1', 'mtu': '', 'netflow': '', 'lldp': 'trusted', 'mgmt': 'ping', 'speed': '', 'duplex': '', 'state': ''}, {'intf': 'ethernet1/4', 'comment': 'To fw1.site', 'mo
de': 'layer3', 'tag': '', 'vlan_name': '', 'vr_name': '', 'ipv4': '169.254.255.3/31', 'ipv6': '', 'zone': 'zone1', 'mtu': '', 'netflow': '', 'lldp': 'trusted', 'mgmt': 'ping', 'speed': '', 'duplex': '', 'state': ''}], 'fw1.site': [{'intf': 'ethernet1/1', 'comment': 'Dot1Q trunk to xyz', 'mode': 'layer2', 'tag': '', 'vlan_name': ''
, 'vr_name': '', 'ipv4': '', 'ipv6': '', 'zone': '', 'mtu': '', 'netflow': '', 'lldp': 'trusted', 'mgmt': '', 'speed': '', 'duplex': '', 'state': ''}, {'intf': 'ethernet1/1.2', 'comment': 'Some VLAN', 'mode': 'layer2', 'tag': '2', 'vlan_name': 'VLAN_2', 'vr_name': '', 'ipv4': '', 'ipv6': '', 'zone': 'zone1', 'mtu': '', 'netflow': '', 'lldp': '', 'mgmt': '', 'speed': '','duplex': '', 'state': ''}]}

TASK [test1] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

['fw1.site', 'fw2.site']

TASK [test2] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=fw2.site) => {}

MSG:

-   comment: To fw1.site
    duplex: ''
    intf: ethernet1/3
    ipv4: 169.254.255.1/31
    ipv6: ''
    lldp: trusted
    mgmt: ping
    mode: layer3
    mtu: ''
    netflow: ''
    speed: ''
    state: ''
    tag: ''
    vlan_name: ''
    vr_name: ''
    zone: zone1
-   comment: To fw1.site
    duplex: ''
    intf: ethernet1/4
    ipv4: 169.254.255.3/31
    ipv6: ''
    lldp: trusted
    mgmt: ping
    mode: layer3
    mtu: ''
    netflow: ''
    speed: ''
    state: ''
    tag: ''
    vlan_name: ''
    vr_name: ''
    zone: zone1

ok: [localhost] => (item=fw1.site) => {}

MSG:

-   comment: Dot1Q trunk to xyz
    duplex: ''
    intf: ethernet1/1
    ipv4: ''
    ipv6: ''
    lldp: trusted
    mgmt: ''
    mode: layer2
    mtu: ''
    netflow: ''
    speed: ''
    state: ''
    tag: ''
    vlan_name: ''
    vr_name: ''
    zone: ''
-   comment: Some VLAN
    duplex: ''
    intf: ethernet1/1.2
    ipv4: ''
    ipv6: ''
    lldp: ''
    mgmt: ''
    mode: layer2
    mtu: ''
    netflow: ''
    speed: ''
    state: ''
    tag: '2'
    vlan_name: VLAN_2
    vr_name: ''
    zone: zone1

Now, I'm able to loop over the hosts, but rather than nesting the loops, I think it would be easier to reformat the CSV read data as follows:
- host: fw1.site
  - intf: ethernet1/1
    comment: blah
    etc: values

As then I think I can use subelements in the loop. Some input would be constructive at this point.

Using subelement in or a simple list with duplicated date is the exact same. What is the output you are trying to achieve?

I want to call a roles task to configure interfaces on devices. The parameters are the values to be parsed, the host is the target.
I aim to loop through all the interfaces read from hostA before moving on to the interfaces for hostB. Simply looping through the devices or the interfaces separately isn't enough. The pan_hosts variable neatly contains a list of the hosts for which files are found (by csv file name).
Nested loops would force me to split the playbook into multiple files. I feel like I'm losing the plot.

Or maybe I'm going about this all wrong?
I guess I could search for the csv files as I do now, but only extract the device names from the file names and just loop over those, calling the roles task for each devies. Then this roles task can read the content of the file line by line for that specific host.

This does not address the comment. What are you trying to achieve in terms of of data structure? Please do [edit] this in your question. As it stands, your question looks like an XY problem to me.
